# Libvirt and TLS ignoring CA file settings

Tags: ssl, kvm, libvirt

I have 3 KVM/libvirt hypervisors that I would like to communicate with each other.
I have my own CA and subordinate CA.

I created the certificates for each machine and I have the following one each /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf of them:

```
listen_tls = 1
key_file = "/etc/pki/tls/private/serverX_libvirt_key.pem"
cert_file = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/serverX_crt.pem"
ca_file = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/CA_chain.pem"
```

The `CA_chain.pem` file obviously contains the chain certificates (Int-CA & CA). 
The key file and the certificates are validated correctly.

```sh
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/CA_chain.pem /etc/pki/tls/certs//etc/pki/tls/certs/serverX_crt.pem
```

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs/serverX_crt.pem: OK
```

Client certificates are defined as in the documentation as:

```sh
ls -lrt /etc/pki/libvirt/private/clientkey.pem
-r--------. 1 root root 3243 Apr  30 09:45 /etc/pki/libvirt/private/clientkey.pem
```

And of course it's verified from our CA:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/CA_chain.pem /etc/pki/libvirt/clientcert.pem
/etc/pki/libvirt/clientcert.pem: OK
```

```sh
ls -lrt /els -lrt /etc/pki/libvirt/clientcert.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2297 Apr  30 10:07 /etc/pki/libvirt/clientcert.pemtc/pki/libvirt/private/clientkey.pem
```

However, I cannot connect to the hypervisors!

Using virsh, I get the following error:

```sh
[root@serverX ~]# virsh -c qemu+tls://serverY list
```

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Cannot read CA certificate '/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem': No such file or directory
```

The certificate permissions are correct, the SELinux is correct. 
But obviously, something is missing and I cannot connect to the servers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it.

The issue seems to be that the libvirt's client has no option for TLS. Thus, we are forced to use the default locations. And although I used the default locations for the private key and the certificate, I didn't do the same for the CA.

Thus, I created a link from `/etc/pki/tls/certs/CA_chain.pem` to `/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem` and now everything is fine.

```sh
mkdir -p /etc/pki/CA/
ln -s /etc/pki/tls/certs/CA_chain.pem /etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem
```